# Can't resolve module dependendcies in Nest.js

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, typeorm

I have been following the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database) on the NestJs website and it jumps around a bit... All I want to do is have it pull an RPG Character pulled from the Mongo database using TypeORM. I am however hitting dependency hell.

The specific error I am getting from Nest is

> [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CharacterModule (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the CharacterModule context.

[Here is a link to the Gist](https://gist.github.com/manchuwook/57581af4545da861e8b84bb5a131c549)

The short bit of code is this:

`character.module.ts`

```js
// tslint:disable: quotemark
import { Module, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

import { CharacterEntity } from "../entities/character.entity";
import { CharacterService } from './character.service';
import { CharacterController } from './character.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    CharacterController
  ],
  providers: [
    CharacterService
  ],
  exports: [
    CharacterService,
  ]
})
export class CharacterModule {
  constructor() { }
}
```

I have tried adding `TypeOrm.forFeature([CharacterEntity], 'default')` and exporting `TypeOrmModule`.  I've also added `@Inject() private connection: Connection` to my constructor for the module as well.

Where am I going wrong?

## Update - 07/26/2020

`new character.module.ts`

```js
// tslint:disable: quotemark
import { Module, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';

import { CharacterEntity } from "../entities/character.entity";
import { CharacterService } from './character.service';
import { CharacterController } from './character.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CharacterEntity])
  ],
  controllers: [
    CharacterController
  ],
  providers: [
    CharacterService
  ],
  exports: [
    CharacterService,
    TypeOrmModule
  ]
})
export class CharacterModule {
  constructor() { }
}
```

`character.service.ts`

```
// tslint:disable: quotemark
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Response as ExpressResponse } from 'express';

import {
 /* other imports */
    Character,
} from 'src/model';
import { CharacterEntity } from '../entities/character.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CharacterService {
    characterNotFound: NotFoundError = {
        errorType: 'Not Found',
        Event_Code: '404',
        Event_Id: '',
        Event_Message: 'The character was not found',
        Event_Subject: 'Character not found',
        Event_Timestamp: new Date().toString()
    } as NotFoundError;

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(CharacterEntity)
        private characterRepo: Repository<CharacterEntity>
    ) { }
/* other actions */
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
// tslint:disable: quotemark
// modules
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CharacterModule } from './character/character.module';
import { CampaignModule } from './campaign/campaign.module';
import { PlayerModule } from './player/player.module';
import { SageModule } from './sage/sage.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

// controllers
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { PlayerController } from './player/player.controller';
import { AuthController } from './auth/auth.controller';

// services
import { AppService } from './app.service';

// constants for everything else
import { SAGE_DB, SAGE_DB_HOST, SAGE_DB_PORT, ENTITIES_PATH } from './constants';
import { CharacterController } from './character/character.controller';
import { CharacterEntity } from './entities/character.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      "name": "default",
      "type": "mongodb",
      "host": SAGE_DB_HOST,
      "port": SAGE_DB_PORT,
      "database": SAGE_DB,
      "keepConnectionAlive": true,
      "synchronize": true,
      "autoLoadEntities": true
    }),
    CharacterModule,
    SageModule,
    CampaignModule,
    PlayerModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
    PlayerController,
    AuthController
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {
    connection.connect().then(f => {
      console.log('fulfilled', f);
    }, r => {
      console.log('rejected', r);
    });
  }
}
```

Returns the error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CharacterEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.` TypeOrmModule.forRoot({...}) is in the `app.module.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CharacterModule` you need to use `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CharacterEntity])` so that the injection token for Repository(CharacterEntity)`is available in the context of the`CharacterModule`.

Comment: That gets me
`[ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CharacterEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.`

Comment: @Manchuwook did you properly initialize the TypeORM connection?

Comment: @Manchuwook do you have `TypeOrmModule.forRoot/Async()` in your `AppModule`? That's how these repository connection objects know what database is bieng connected to. If you are getting an error about `Connection` in the `TypeOrmModule` you _probably_ don't have the registration of that module called.

Comment: `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({... ormConfig ...})` is called on app.module.ts and initialized as connection in the constructor

Comment: Strange, everything you have looks like it should be correct. Is there any chance you can share your full repository? Or a reproduction? Everything looks like it is marked properly.

Answer (score 0):

When using the repository pattern I found it necessary to use forRoot and forFeature to achieve what I needed.
**ormconfig** in this example is basically what you already have (db connection settings). The **arrayofentities** is an array of each of the typescript entity classes.

The way you are currently making use of the repository pattern in your services shouldn't require you to import **Connection** either.

(Please note the following is all in app.module.ts you could put the for feature part in your specific module)

```
imports:[
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature(arrayofentities)
    ]
```

Comment: Further. Is there a reason you are exporting the TypeOrmModule as well?

Comment: I can at least say exporting the `TypeOrmModule` is useful when it comes to re-using the same entity in another provider, but generally I would prefer to export the service alone and not worry about multiple typeorm modules/repositories in a single service.

Comment: That was more the reason for the question @JayMcDoniel definitely simpler ways of achieving the same result here.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error because I was Importing Repository and another service with the "type" keyword in front.

Wrong:

```
import type { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import type { FileUtilsService } from "../file-utils";
```

Correct:

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { FileUtilsService } from "../file-utils";
```